# if specific text is in cell return a certain value. multiple "specific texts" and multiple values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

[image: 1]

I have this spread sheet that currently i manually fill out much to my frustration, as I can't work out how to automate it.

Columns a b and c are from an export from my webstore. I use this sheet to export all the orders for the week and then figure out how much of what coffee I need to order. The export is clunky and product info is grouped together.

What I want to do is...
If any cells in B contain "Blend subscription" then place value into column F
If any cells in B contain "Filter subscription" then place value into column D
If any cells in B contain "Espresso subscription" then place value into column E

The values are 250, 450, 900 and relate to a specific text in column C
If cells in column C contain "small" then value is 250
If cells in column C contain "medium" then value is 450
If cells in column C contain "large" then value is 900

The values relate to grams of coffee. They are normally input by me manually

I hope this makes sense because It's confusing me! I've tried versions of Vlookup and countif but nothing quite works.

Comment: Your data are not clear: is the value 250 or 450 anywhere to be seen in the data? Can you edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Within Sheets here's a sample setup and a working formula you can test out.

Cell D2 formula:

`=INDEX(MAP(B2:B8,C2:C8,LAMBDA(bx,cx,IF(REGEXMATCH(bx,"(?i)"&D1:G1&" subscription"),SWITCH(REGEXEXTRACT(cx,"Grind: (.*?),"),"Small",250,"Medium",450,"Large",900),))))`

-

[image]

**FINAL UPDATED FORMULA**:

`=INDEX(MAP(B2:B9,C2:C9,LAMBDA(bx,cx,IF(bx="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(bx,"(?i)"&D1:G1&" subscription"),SWITCH(REGEXEXTRACT(cx,"Small|Medium|Large"),"Small",250,"Medium",450,"Large",900),)))))`

Comment: thank you! works for some but not others because in column C the prodcut descriptions sometimes appear slightly different like so...note, no "grind" on the bottom one

Size, Roast, Grind: Medium
Size &amp; Roast: Medium

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample demo sheet recreating this scenario so that we can check it out directly and work it out.

Comment: sure, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_CsXJkQDd9fT9mWgqCtAKnBfYP3_VgB386tR4yoBps/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Updated the formula. Please check it out.

Comment: Holy moly, thank you so much!